# Accumulative Update for previous records

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, accumulate

I have table that shows these information

```
Month   NewClients   OnHoldClients
5-2017  10           2
6-2017  16           4
7-2017  11           1
8-2017  15           6
9-2017  18           7
```

I am trying to find the accumulative total for each month
which is

***(NewClients - OnHoldClients) + Previous Month Total***

Something like this

```
Month   NewClients   OnHoldClients   Total
5-2017  10           2               8
6-2017  16           4               20
7-2017  11           1               30
8-2017  15           6               39
9-2017  18           7               50
```

the query i tried to build was something like this but I think should be an easier way to do that

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Total = (SELECT TOP 1 Total FROM MyTable B WHERE B.Month < A.Month) + NewClients - OnHoldClients
FROM MyTable A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we begin, note the mere fact that you're facing such calculative problem is a symptom that maybe you don't have the best possible design. Normally for this purpose calculated values are being stored along the way as the records are inserted. So i'd say you'd better have a total field to begin with and calculate it as records amass.

Now let's get down to the problem at hand. i composed a query which does that nicely but it's a bit verbose due to recursive nature of the problem. However, it yields the exact expected result:

```
DECLARE @dmin AS date = (SELECT min(mt.[Month]) from dbo.MyTable mt);

;WITH cte(_Month, _Total) AS (
    SELECT mt.[Month] AS _Month, (mt.NewClients - mt.OnHoldClients) AS _Total
    FROM dbo.MyTable mt
    WHERE mt.[Month] = @dmin

    UNION ALL

    SELECT mt.[Month] AS _Month, ((mt.NewClients - mt.OnHoldClients) + ccc._Total) AS _Total
    FROM dbo.MyTable mt
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT cc._Total FROM (SELECT c._Total, 
                        CAST((row_number() OVER (ORDER BY c._Month DESC)) AS int) as _Rank 
                        FROM cte c WHERE c._Month < mt.[Month]) as cc
                WHERE cc._Rank = 1) AS ccc
    WHERE mt.[Month] > @dmin
)

SELECT c._Month, max(c._Total) AS Total
FROM cte c
GROUP BY c._Month
```

It is a recursive CTE structure that goes about each record all along the way to the initial month and adds up to the final Total value. This query only includes Month and Total fields but you can easily add the other 2 to the list of projection.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE([Month],NewClients,OnHoldClients)
AS
(
SELECT '5-2017',10,2 UNION ALL
SELECT '6-2017',16,4 UNION ALL
SELECT '7-2017',11,1 UNION ALL
SELECT '8-2017',15,6 UNION ALL
SELECT '9-2017',18,7
)
SELECT [Month],
        NewClients,
        OnHoldClients,
        SUM(MonthTotal)OVER( ORDER BY [Month]) AS Total
FROM
(
SELECT [Month],
        NewClients,
        OnHoldClients,
        SUM(NewClients-OnHoldClients)OVER(PArtition by [Month] Order by [Month]) AS MonthTotal
FROM CTE
)dt
```

Result,Demo:http://rextester.com/DKLG54359

```
Month   NewClients  OnHoldClients   Total
--------------------------------------------
5-2017      10          2            8
6-2017      16          4            20
7-2017      11          1            30
8-2017      15          6            39
9-2017      18          7            50
```